# Unable to start Weblogic server by using startWebLogic.sh

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to start WebLogic server 12.2.1.4.0 by using startWebLogic.sh.
And I am using the oracle JDK 14,which I think the latest version.
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html

I can find it in the starting log.

```
####<Jun 8, 2020, 8:35:19,524 PM China Standard Time> <Info> <Management> <iZwz9e2m2pgknyfitqjloeZ> <> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1591619720107> <[partition-name: DOMAIN] [severity-value: 64] [partition-id: 0] > <BEA-141278> <Java entropy configuration is: System property "java.security.egd= null"; JRE's java.security file property "securerandom.source= file:/dev/random"; Blocking Config= true; JDK version= 14.0.1; Operating System= Linux.> 
####<Jun 8, 2020, 8:35:19,729 PM China Standard Time> <Info> <Management> <iZwz9e2m2pgknyfitqjloeZ> <> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1591619720114> <[partition-name: DOMAIN] [severity-value: 64] [partition-id: 0] > <BEA-141279> <Detected BLOCKING java entropy configuration. This is the most secure setting, but may cause performance issues on machines with few sources of entropy.> 
####<Jun 8, 2020, 8:35:19,738 PM China Standard Time> <Info> <Management> <iZwz9e2m2pgknyfitqjloeZ> <> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1591619720114> <[partition-name: DOMAIN] [severity-value: 64] [partition-id: 0] > <BEA-141187> <Java system properties are defined as follows: 
file.encoding = UTF-8
file.separator = /
java.class.path = /work/weblogic/webl/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/work/weblogic/webl/wlserver/../oracle_common/modules/thirdparty/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar:/work/weblogic/webl/wlserver/modules/features/oracle.wls.common.nodemanager.jar:/work/weblogic/webl/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbynet.jar:/work/weblogic/webl/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar:/work/weblogic/webl/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derby.jar
java.class.version = 58.0
java.home = /usr/java/jdk-14.0.1
java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
java.library.path = ::/work/weblogic/webl/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64:/work/weblogic/webl/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64/oci920_8:/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
java.naming.factory.initial = weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs = weblogic.jndi.factories:weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.url:weblogic.jndi.factories:weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.url
java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version = 14.0.1+7
java.security.policy = /work/weblogic/webl/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.policy
java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version = 14
java.system.class.loader = com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader
java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url = https://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug = https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/
java.version = 14.0.1
java.version.date = 2020-04-14
java.vm.compressedOopsMode = 32-bit
java.vm.info = mixed mode, sharing
java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version = 14
java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version = 14.0.1+7
javax.management.builder.initial = weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder
javax.rmi.CORBA.PortableRemoteObjectClass = weblogic.iiop.PortableRemoteObjectDelegateImpl
javax.rmi.CORBA.UtilClass = weblogic.iiop.UtilDelegateImpl
jdk.debug = release
jdk.jfr.repository = /tmp/2020_06_08_20_35_19_29662
launch.use.env.classpath = true
org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass = weblogic.corba.orb.ORB
org.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass = weblogic.corba.orb.ORB
os.arch = amd64
os.name = Linux
os.version = 3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64
path.separator = :
sun.arch.data.model = 64
sun.boot.library.path = /usr/java/jdk-14.0.1/lib
sun.cpu.endian = little
sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
sun.java.command = weblogic.Server
sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
user.country = US
user.dir = /work/weblogic/webl/user_projects/domains/basicWLSDomain
user.home = /work/weblogic
user.language = en
user.name = weblogic
user.timezone = Asia/Shanghai
vde.home = /work/weblogic/webl/user_projects/domains/basicWLSDomain/servers/AdminServer/data/ldap
weblogic.Name = AdminServer
weblogic.home = /work/weblogic/webl/wlserver/server
wls.home = /work/weblogic/webl/wlserver/server
.>
```

Bellow is the error:

```
A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NullPointerException
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on weblogic.management.partition.admin.PartitionManagerService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.oracle.weblogic.lifecycle.core.PartitionLCMService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.oracle.weblogic.lifecycle.core.PartitionLCMService
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:250)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103)
        at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151)
        at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134)
        at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95)
        at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> <Jun 8, 2020, 8:35:22,703 PM China Standard Time> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED.> <Jun 8, 2020, 8:35:22,703 PM China Standard Time> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down.> <Jun 8, 2020, 8:35:22,705 PM China Standard Time> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN.> <Jun 8, 2020, 8:35:22,721 PM China Standard Time> <Warning> <JMX> <BEA-149513> <JMX Connector Server stopped at service:jmx:iiop://172.18.221.70:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.edit.> <Jun 8, 2020, 8:35:22,724 PM China Standard Time> <Warning> <JMX> <BEA-149513> <JMX Connector Server stopped at service:jmx:iiop://172.18.221.70:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.> <Jun 8, 2020, 8:35:22,741 PM China Standard Time> <Warning> <JMX> <BEA-149513> <JMX Connector Server stopped at service:jmx:iiop://172.18.221.70:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime.> Stopping Derby server... Derby server stopped.
```

Bellow is the stacktrace found in AdminServer.log:

```
A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NullPointerException
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on weblogic.management.partition.admin.PartitionManagerService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.oracle.weblogic.lifecycle.core.PartitionLCMService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.oracle.weblogic.lifecycle.core.PartitionLCMService

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:250)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:786)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95)
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:698)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:683)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ConstructorActionImpl$2.run(ConstructorActionImpl.java:118)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ConstructorActionImpl.makeMe(ConstructorActionImpl.java:108)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ConstructorInterceptorHandler.construct(ConstructorInterceptorHandler.java:82)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:286)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:786)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

Have anyone met this problem before and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you share the error message from the server's log including the complete stack trace ?

Comment: Are you using a JDK above 1.8??

Comment: Thanks for replying,I have add the complete stack trace found in the AdminServer.log. @EmmanuelCollin

Comment: @GerardoArroyo Thanks for replying.I think I am using the latest version of Oracle JDK. And I 
 can find it in the log.Please check what I added in the question.  https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html

Comment: @JasonYang, as far as I know, Weblogic will need a Oracle JDK 1.8. JDK 14 it not in the certification matrix

Comment: I confirm that WLS 12c is not certified with Java 14. You should use Java 8 instead.
WLS 14c supports java 8 and java 11.

Comment: Thank you very much.I changed the JDK version to 8 and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using JDK 14 which is why WebLogic doesn't start.

I tried WebLogic 12C with a number of JDK versions. It gives this and other exceptions on any JDK version higher than 1.8.0_341.